# Unable to call Generic method Enumerable.Where

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, .net-4.5

Here is my code - i am trying to generate Lambda

```
public static void CallIEnumerableWhere()
{
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();
    lst.Add(1);
    lst.Add(2);
    lst.Add(3);
    Type console = typeof(Enumerable);
    var tt = console.GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Where")).ToList()[0];

    var genericParam1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IEnumerable<>)));

    MethodInfo method2 = tt.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IEnumerable<>));
    var args = tt.GetGenericArguments();

    ParameterExpression lambdaParam2 = Expression.Parameter(args[0]);
    Expression methodCall = Expression.Call(null, method2, lambdaParam2);
    //^^ERROR ON THIS LINE^^^

    //var finalLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<...>...

}
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I am trying to emulate:

```
int z = 1;
lst.Where(x => x == z)
```

This is Error which i get at Runtime:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Method
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]]
>   Where[IEnumerable`1](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]],
>   System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T],System.Boolean])
>   contains generic parameters

Please assist.

Comment: you need to add some more information, e.g. what does error mean (what is the error, compile time, run time, etc)

Comment: [Copy the exception details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and add them to your question as a edit.

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be using `Expression` at all when dealing with an `IEnumerable`.  There are *much* simpler and more effective tools at your disposal when dealing entirely with in-memory data manipulated by your application.

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama,@scott - Added the error.

Comment: @Servy - my requirement is that i get a class name at runtime for which i need to generate a Lambda on an ienumerable collection.

Comment: @ExpertNovice It looks like your code can only ever handle an input collection of `int` types, not any type, so even using your own code you haven't solved that problem at all.  If you don't know what the type of the input sequence is, how do you intend to compare those items to `1`?

Comment: @Servy - this is the first step i am trying to achieve - then i will change my code further to make it more generic. `1` will be a runtime input.

Comment: @ExpertNovice Then just use `object.Equals` to compare the objects.

Comment: @Servy - i need to convert the query later into an Iqueryable to use in Entity Framework.

Comment: @ExpertNovice Then none of the code that you have here is of any good, because you're not working with an `IQueryable` in your code at all.   You should also be stating that in the question, because that's highly relevant.

Comment: @Servy- This itself is too much for me. I mustered up some of this after 3 days research. That is expecting too much with my current knowledge of Expression Trees.

Comment: Using `IQueryable` would likely be actually easier here. In particular with `Enumerable` and `IEnumerable` the `x => x == z` is a `Func<int, bool>`, but with `Queryable` and `IQueryable` then `x => x == z` is an `Expression<Func<int, bool>>` and that's easier to combine with other expressions.

Comment: `typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IEnumerable<>)` that bit produces what `typeof(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>)` would produce if C# allowed that. You presumably want `typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int))` there.